# Advanced gmail settings missing on iPad?

Tags: ios, ipad, gmail, settings

I'm trying to make some changes to my gmail account on my iPad. All recommendations ask me to go into Settings, select mt gmail account, then select "Advanced" 
which I don't *have* as an option...
What am I missing?

Comment: Could you provide links to some of the recommendations that you're talking about.

Answer (score 1):

The route is Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendars > [Name of your Gmail account]

On the first row of this screen it says Gmail and just below that, "Account"; to the right is the name of your account and an arrow.

[image: mail app, gmail settings]

Tap on the arrow. The "Account" screen is opened.

[image: mail app, gmail Account screen]

On the bottom row there is an "Advanced" button, tap on it.

[image: mail app, Gmail settings, advanced]

Comment: Thank you!  (I have no earthly idea why I didn't see that.  I looked three times!)  Got it now.  Thx again, Kelly